# Where to store credentials for a tird-party API in my API?

Tags: rest, api-design, authorization

So my current app process works like this:

- Client communicates with my API to get certain information
- My API needs information from a third-party API and uses these to create a response for the client
- API sends response back to client

However, in order to access the third-party API I have to provide a basic authentication with `loginname` and `password` base64 encoded.

My question is where do I store the credentials for the third party API. I do not want and need a human to enter any credentials in this process.

Answer (score 2):

Credentials are sensitive data that needs to be stored securely, audited to see who has accessed them and easy to manage and replace if they expire without needing to update your code or roll out a new config. For that, the best choice is a Secret Storage solution of some sort.

Cloud providers have this service (Secrets Manager on AWS or GCP, KeyVault on Azure) that can be easily accessed, audited and updated. There might be local solutions as well.

Remember that most 3rd party services probably have policies in their TOS that require you to store credentials safely, and if your credentials are stolen and used for illegal or unapproved uses, you're the one responsible for them.

Comment: "There might be local solutions as well." <- an HSM is the traditional local solution.

Comment: HSM might be _part_ of a solution, the part responsible for securely encrypting the credentials, but you still need a software solution for the auditing and credential rotation.

Answer (score 1):

Login credentials are volatile information, i.e. they can change at a moment's notice without the actual code/logic needing to be changed. Therefore, you want to store them in a way that these can be altered without touching the deployed application.

This essentially means that you'll be storing them in your config file. How that config file is managed depends on your environment. If you're using Azure, for example, you can use an app configuration resources which distributes the configuration options to your application(s).

You could similarly store them in your database, if you're already relying on your db for other config settings.